# Search for a string and print or grep lines between a pattern in a big log file with python

Tags: python, search

Search for a string in a big log file with python and

1. print or grep lines between the lines that started with dashes
2. also print only the 1st line that has the date

Here is the paragraph from a log file that I have and need help to search for the string "AMQ6209W" and then print all the lines between the lines that have dashes. Number of lines vary between the string the dashes depending upon the error message, which is the reason we cannot really grep using the no of lines there. To look like a real log, you can append this couple of times and update the AMQ error to AMQ1111W and AMQ1112W, so you can find for AMQ6209W.

```
----- amqxfdcx.c : 1145 -------------------------------------------------------
02/05/2024 12:15:45 AM - Process(58674.2) User(mqm) Program(runmqlsr)
                    Host(abc.com) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(7.5.0.15) QMgr(TEST)
                    Time(2024-02-05T05:15:45.505Z)
                    ArithInsert1(1) ArithInsert2(1)
                    CommentInsert1(SIGHUP)
                    CommentInsert2(Signal sent by pid 1)
                    CommentInsert3(systemd)

AMQ6209W: An unexpected asynchronous signal (1 : SIGHUP) has been received and
ignored.


EXPLANATION:
Process 1 received an unexpected asynchronous signal and ignored it. This has
not caused an error but the source of the signal should be determined as it is
likely that the signal has been generated externally to IBM MQ.
ACTION:
Determine the source of the signal and prevent it from re-occurring.
----- amqxerrx.c : 855 --------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried this but i'm not getting anywhere:

```py
from itertools import islice
index = 0
with open("/home/AMQERR01.LOG", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        index += 1
        if "AMQ6209W" in line:
            print("hello")
            f.seek(0)
            print("".join(islice(f, index - 10, index + 8)))
            print("hello1")
```

Comment: I can only see an unindented version of your Python code, but it looks like you are applying the `seek()` method on the very file over which you are iterating. That would be a prescription for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

If we have the lines of your logfile in a list, we can use `itertools.groupby` to find only those between `---` lines.

```
[
  list(v) 
  for k, v in itertools.groupby(lines, key=lambda line: line.startswith('---')) 
  if not k
]
```

Output:

```
[
  ['02/05/2024 12:15:45 AM - Process(58674.2) User(mqm) Program(runmqlsr)', 
   '                    Host(abc.com) Installation(Installation1)', 
   '                    VRMF(7.5.0.15) QMgr(TEST)', 
   '                    Time(2024-02-05T05:15:45.505Z)', 
   '                    ArithInsert1(1) ArithInsert2(1)', 
   '                    CommentInsert1(SIGHUP)', 
   '                    CommentInsert2(Signal sent by pid 1)', 
   '                    CommentInsert3(systemd)', 
   '', 
   'AMQ6209W: An unexpected asynchronous signal (1 : SIGHUP) has been received and', 

   'ignored.', 
   '', 
   '', 
   'EXPLANATION:', 
   'Process 1 received an unexpected asynchronous signal and ignored it. This has', 
   'not caused an error but the source of the signal should be determined as it is', 
   'likely that the signal has been generated externally to IBM MQ.', 
   'ACTION:', 
   'Determine the source of the signal and prevent it from re-occurring.'
  ]
]
```

Modify it a little further and we can pull out the lines you're looking for:

```
[
  [
    line 
    for line in lst 
    if 'AMQ6209W' in line
  ] 
  for k, v in itertools.groupby(lines, key=lambda line: line.startswith('---')) 
  for lst in (list(v),) 
  if not k
]
```

Result:

```
[
  ['AMQ6209W: An unexpected asynchronous signal (1 : SIGHUP) has been received and']
]
```

Answer (score 0):

## record-oriented grep

Grep is a handy utility.
It works with newline-delimited records.

Your records are multi-line and use a different delimiter.
Here is one way to do record matching.

```py
from io import TextIOWrapper
from typing import Generator
import re


record_boundary_re = re.compile(r"^----- ")


def get_records(f: TextIOWrapper) -> Generator[list[str], None, None]:
    record: list[str] = []
    for line in f:
        if record_boundary_re.match(line):
            if record:
                yield record
            record = []
        record.append(line.rstrip())

    if record:
        yield record


def grep(needle="AMQ6209W", in_file="/tmp/log.txt") -> None:
    with open(in_file) as fin:
        for record in get_records(fin):
            if needle in "\n".join(record):
                for line in record:
                    print(bold(line) if needle in line else line)


def bold(s: str) -> str:
    """Adds ANSI escape codes to emphasize text."""
    return f"\033[1m{s}\033[0m"
```

---

EDIT

Stripping off the optional type annotations is straightforward:

```
import re


record_boundary_re = re.compile(r"^----- ")


def get_records(f):
    record: list[str] = []
    for line in f:
        if record_boundary_re.match(line):
            if record:
                yield record
            record = []
        record.append(line.rstrip())

    if record:
        yield record


def grep(needle="AMQ6209W", in_file="/tmp/log.txt"):
    with open(in_file) as fin:
        for record in get_records(fin):
            if needle in "\n".join(record):
                for line in record:
                    print(bold(line) if needle in line else line)


def bold(s):
    """Adds ANSI escape codes to emphasize text."""
    return f"\033[1m{s}\033[0m"
```

Comment: Here is the error msg:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./log_read_new.py", line 10, in <module>
    def get_records(f: TextIOWrapper) -> Generator[list[str], None, None]:
NameError: name 'TextIOWrapper' is not defined

Comment: I should have added in the relevant `import`s, for folks not using PyCharm or a similarly capable IDE that auto adds them. Done. The type annotations assume a modern interpreter; I am using 3.11.7.

Comment: sorry, i'm running the script using Python 3.6.8, still seeing issue:
$ python3 log_read_new.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "log_read_new.py", line 12, in <module>
    def get_records(f: TextIOWrapper) -> Generator[list[str], None, None]:
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Python 3.6 went EOL (end of life) some years ago. You can try to use the optional type annotation syntax with it, but that won’t work. Simply elide it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Python#Table_of_versions

Comment: sorry i'm out of luck there with the latest version. thank you for your help there!!!
Will try with with simple enumeration to go few line before and after. Not sure if there is a way to get to the closest line with dashes to print out only that instance, using enumeration..

Comment: @ravi, stripping off the optional type annotations is straightforward.